# Running the custom Debugger JAVA

Tags: java, c++, jvmti

I am trying to run the custom debugger agent which is written in C++ using the JVMTI interface. I followed the following link

[Creating a Debugging and Profiling Agent with JVMTI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jvmti-136367.html)

I am trying to run the debugger which is present in the demo folder of jdk, using the following command `java -Xbootclasspath/a:mtrace.jar -agentlib:mtrace`
the jvm is not booting up it's giving me the following output

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library mtrace on the library path, with error: Can't find dependent libraries
```

i have added the folder containing the library file to the PATH variable, still no luck, what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-agentpath:/path/to/mtrace` (The absolute path) to locate the agent library. The `PATH` environment variable only provides path to the terminal commands. Native agent library path has to be set using `-agentpath` runtime flag.

With `-agentpath` you don't have to use `-agentlib` switch.